# My Bullet is not getting instantiated where my Player is. It is getting instantiated from center only

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity & on Stackoverflow. Need your help as I am stuck in this below mentioned situation.
When I spawn my projectile(Bullet), It should be instantiated at player's current position but It's not getting changed. The bullet is getting generated from Center only(Not from Player's position). Please advise.  [image is for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDI0R.png)

### SpawnobjectController Script

```
public class SpawnobjectController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
     GameObject projectilereference;
    
    [SerializeField]
     GameObject enemyreference;

    [SerializeField]
     GameObject playerreference;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Enemycoroutine());
        StartCoroutine(ProjectileCoroutine());
 }

     
    void SpawnProjectile() 
    {
        
        Instantiate(projectilereference, new Vector3(playerreference.transform.position.x,projectilereference.transform.position.y,0.0f), Quaternion.identity);
    }

    IEnumerator ProjectileCoroutine() 
    {
        while (true)
        {
            SpawnProjectile();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
        }
    }



    IEnumerator Enemycoroutine()
    {
        while (true) { 
        SpawnEnemy();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
    }
    }
    void SpawnEnemy() 
    {
        Instantiate(enemyreference, enemyreference.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

### PlayerController Scripts

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    float _horizontalAxisPlayer;
    float _playerSpeed = 5f;
    float _maxXBoundry = 2.31f;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        ControlPlayerBoundries();
        PlayerMovement();
    }

    void PlayerMovement() 
    {
        _horizontalAxisPlayer = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*_playerSpeed*Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(_horizontalAxisPlayer, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    }

    void ControlPlayerBoundries() 
    {
        if (transform.position.x>_maxXBoundry)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(_maxXBoundry,transform.position.y,0.0f);
        }
        else if (transform.position.x<-_maxXBoundry)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(-_maxXBoundry, transform.position.y, 0.0f);
        }

    }
}
```

### EnemyController

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float enemeySpeed = 2f;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.down * enemeySpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

ProjectileController Script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ProjectileController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
   private GameObject Playerref;
    [SerializeField]
    private float projectile_speed = 2f;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
      //  print(Playerref.transform.position);
        
       
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(transform.position.x, 0.5f) * projectile_speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: `SpawnProjectile` is using the `x` and `y` from the player, not `x` and `z`. `y` is up, so try using the `x` and `z` of the player to match the player's location, and play with a positive `y` value to set the height of where the bullet starts.

Comment: @ps2goat  First of all, Thank you so much for your prompt reply. 

I changed Spawnprojectile method as below:   But still getting the same result. Bullet getting generated from the center only.  Sorry if I misunderstood your answer request you help.

`void SpawnProjectile() 
    {
        
        Instantiate(projectilereference, new Vector3(playerreference.transform.position.x,projectilereference.transform.position.y,playerreference.transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
    }`

Comment: Your spawn object uses player for x but a prefab for y. So probably zero.

Comment: Hi @BugFinder, Thank you. Could you please help me with what changes I need to make in this code So I can get the expected result. please advise.

Comment: That is fairly specific. Aa you wrote the code. Look to where you instantiate a projectile and look at the x and y

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely in the script that translates your bullet.
As the code you shared does exactly what you want. Assuming we are in a front view.

I have verified this by using your script and a copy of the enemy script in place of a bullet that moves them in `Vector3.Up` direction.

**Edit:**
You are creating a new vector with the transforms x and 0,5f that gets added every frame.
You either set `transform.position` or use Translate but with a direction only.

```
Moves the transform in the direction and distance of translation.
transform.Translate(Vector3 translation)
```

The following line would work instead.

```
private void LateUpdate()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.up * projectile_speed* Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Comment: Hello ephb, 

I have just added here my ProjectileController Script (that translate Bullet). Please check it & help me.

Comment: Did that solve your problem?